# After minimize remote desktop screen, Keyboard Hook Procedure is not working in C# Window Application

Tags: c#, remote-desktop, rdp, keyboard-hook

I have a C# Window Application that can be used to connected remote desktop computers like Remote Desktop Connection(mstsc) service. This application is used to record the activities of users who used the remote desktop by capturing image when every keyboard actions and mouse actions is occurred on remote desktop screen.

Inside source code, there are keyboard hook procedure(KeyboardHookProc) and mouse hook procedure(MouseHookProc) and install these hook procedure into OS's Hook chain using "SetWindowsHookEx".

It is okay to capture images for every keyboard and mouse actions doing on remote desktop screen
until user click "Minimize Button" of remote desktop screen.

After user minimize remote desktop, then maximize the remote desktop screen again,
capturing process for keyboard actions is not working and OS cannot work my keyboard procedure .But it is still capturing image for mouse actions.

This problem is only occurred on Windows Server 2008 R2.
It is okay on Windows XP.

So if anybody have experience about this problem, let me know any opinion.

Regards,
Tin Linn..

Comment: is it posible that there is a timeout occurring during the time it is minimized? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655278/what-can-cause-windows-to-unhook-a-low-level-global-keyboard-hook?rq=1 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065832/keyboard-hook-stops-working-after-using-remote-desktop

Comment: Yes, I already tested it.But this problem is still occurring and it does not work.